# libcurl - опция CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION

Tags: c++, c, curl

Позвольте несколько вопросов по опции licurl: CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, которая устанавливает обратный вызов функции при приемке новых данных и по нескольким дополнительным смежным опциям.

**1**) Вопрос по CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION:----->

В документации сказано:

> Функция обратного вызова будет передавать как можно больше данных при
> всех вызовах, но вы не должны делать никаких предположений. Это может
> быть один байт, а может быть и тысячи. Максимальный объем данных тела,
> который будет передан функции обратного вызова записи, определен в
> файле заголовка curl.h : CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE (обычное значение по
> умолчанию - 16 КБ). Если CURLOPT_HEADER включен, что позволяет
> передавать данные заголовка в обратный вызов записи, вы можете
> получить до CURL_MAX_HTTP_HEADER байтов данных заголовка, переданных в
> него. Обычно это означает 100К.

-Под 100К - имеется ввиду все тот же размер данных за один приход ?
-Написано, что "Если CURLOPT_HEADER включен, то позволяет ... 100К". Однако в документации к CURLOPT_HEADER сказано, что не опция CURLOPT_HEADER поддерживает 100K, а опция обратного вызова для заголовков CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION поддерживает 100K.  Это небольшая неточность в документации ?

**2**) Вопрос по CURLOPT_HEADER:----->

> Далее: обратный вызов CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION ограничен только
> получением максимального количества переданных ему байтов
> CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE (16 КБ), в то время как заголовок может быть
> длиннее, а CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION поддерживает вызов с заголовками до
> CURL_MAX_HTTP_HEADER bytes (100KBB).

-Подскажите, тут имеется ввиду, то, то заголовок может быть более 16K и его получение просто займет больше вызовов обратной функции CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION  ? То есть грубо говоря ничего потеряно не будет, просто call-back будет вызываться чаще, так как принимает более маленькими порциями ?

**3**) И еще один вопрос по опции CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION:

> Эта функция может быть вызвана с нулевыми байтами данных, если
> переданный файл пуст. Данные, передаваемые в эту функцию, не будут
> завершаться нулевым символом в конце!

Не могу понять, что это может значит ? Зачем эта функция может быть вызвана с нулевым байтом данных и как на это реагировать ?

В чистых сокетах или портах завершения Windows, если функция WSARecv вызывалась с нулевыми данными - это значило, что соединение разварено со стороны севера. Тут то же самое или что то другое ?
Главный вопрос, как на это нужно реагировать ?